# Can I use tabs to organize content, if the content is halfway down the screen?

Tags: android, material-design

I'm designing an android app, using material design, where people can listen to and comment on audiobooks. When a user finishes a chapter, he or she unlocks the comments for that chapter. These comments are displayed below the play, pause, and skip buttons, like this:

[image]

The problem is that there are three main types of comments: typical written comments, audio comments that are recorded in app, and discussion questions that can be answered. The way I can think of to organize these comments is by using tabs, like this:

[image]

This method looks bizarre because the tabs are so similar to the header and it goes against the material design guidelines. So my question is, is there a better way to organize content that is halfway down the screen?

Comment: What is the bottom sheet (black background) used for?

Comment: That is just the android navigation bar (the system wide navigation).

Comment: Ah right, I forgot they include that in the material design wireframes. Thanks!

Comment: Is there a reason why you have to have the book cover on this screen? That seems to be taking a lot of space for something they already know they are listening to.

Comment: @Majo0od Good point, not really. Originally there weren't any comments, so it was just for aesthetics, since there was space.

Comment: I see. Well ok, best of luck with finding the right design mate!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree that it doesn't look great.

Do you need to feature a specific comment?

If not, then I think a successful approach with material design is to have a bottom sheet that slides up to full screen with the tab control:

[image: music]

These would not be tabs but as the sheet slides up it can morph into a top-aligned tab control, with whatever tab the user selected when she tapped on comment, audio or discussions.

For a media player it's nice to keep the interface simple.  You have a lot going on in the page, so removing the featured comment and simplifying the tab control into a dark bottom sheet may help calm the interface.

Answer (score 3):

Are you married to the idea of the tabs? What if you simplified the entire view and provided all replies, with an appropriate action to view/listen? This allows the user to quickly browse all the replies without having to jump around.

Suggestion for on-tap actions per comment type:

- Comments: Either expands or slides over
- Audio Comment: Audio plays immediately, with the icon changing to a pause button
- Discussion: Slides over to discussion panel

[image: Proof of concept for an interactive comments panel]

I also wasn't sure where you were inviting users to add new comments, so I threw a rough placement in for that as well, but you'd need to consider the three types of comment.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the tab bar pattern is bad in itself but the current one looks visually too heavy. How about a lighter colored tab bar like this one seen in the material design guidelines?

[image: light colored tab bar]